# Is there a view/widget to show details of language elements in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In Eclipse, there is a view called "ABAP Element Info", which can show details about language elements such as functions, classes, etc. when they are clicked on. It will display details such as function/method signature, class/struct members, element documentation, etc. as you can see on the image below:

[image: 1]

It is a great help for me and it's very quick to find out details of elements, but I cannot find anything like it in Visual Studio standard package (except Object Browser, but I does not show what I click on, I need to look it up). Is there any extension or something  with similar functionality I could make use of? I'm using C++ desktop version if it helps. Thanks a lot for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Visual Studio, try to check if your project is fully supported and operational in Visual Studio Code.

In VSCode there are various plugins for ABAP development, including syntax highlighting which is your main concern.

Check out the following article on how to prepare your environment:
https://blogs.sap.com/2019/12/06/abap-development-in-vs-code/